# Is the following a property of Hausdorff Spaces?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(X,\mathfrak{T})$ be a Hausdorff Space and $x,y\in X$ such that $x\ne y$. Then is it true that there will always exist $U\ni x$ and $V\ni y$ with $U$ open and $V$ closed in $X$?

I don't think that this is true in general but can't find any counterexample. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. If $X$ is a Hausdorff space, then every singleton is closed. Just take $U$ to be an open set separating $x$ from $y$, and $V=\{y\}$.

But it is really just enough to consider $T_1$ spaces for this, you don't need to go full Hausdorff.

Comment: "go full Hausdorff" is going to be my new verb to describe people who went *just barely* above the bare minimum asked of them.

Comment: Why in a Hausdorff Space every singleton is closed?

Comment: @user170039: Given $y$, for every $x\in X$ you can find an open set $U$ such that $y\notin U$ and $x\in U$. Take the union of all these open sets, it gives you a covering of $X\setminus\{y\}$. Which means exactly that $X\setminus\{y\}$ is open, and therefore $\{y\}$ is closed. Note the proof didn't go full Hausdorff either, just $T_1$ separation.

Comment: "Take the union of all these open sets, it gives you a covering of $X\setminus \{y\}$."- why? and why does this mean that $X\setminus \{y\}$ is open?

Comment: @user170039: Every $x\in X\setminus\{y\}$ lies in at least one of the open sets that you've put in the union; $y$ does not lie in any of them; and it is a union of open sets so the axioms of topology say that it is open.